# ActiveX component can't create object. when trying to set an instance of Outlook

Tags: outlook

So I'm running into a small issue. I have a legacy VB6 application currently running on Windows 7 with Outlook 2007.

We allow the user to send an email, by simply clicking a button (it generates some paperwork and emails it to another person). I initialize Outlook like this...

```
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application

If OutApp Is Nothing = True Then
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
```

I can have Outlook open and it works without any issues. On SET OUTAPP=New Outlook.Application - it works without any issues.

Now when I try to run this in Windows 10, Office 16 - I cannot do the same thing when Outlook is open. It gives me an error stating that

> ActiveX component can't create object.

I'm using the same exact code and each time it gives me an error on Set OutApp=New Outlook.Application.

Any idea why?

Comment: Is either app running with elevated privileges (Run As Administrator)?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko in Win 10 both are run as administrator (outlook and IDE)

Comment: "administrator" as in "local account with admin privileges"? Or did you explicitly click on the app and select "Run As Administrator"?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - I did not select RUN AS ADMIN, it's local account with admin privelages.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - any idea - it works in Windows 7, but doesnt in Windows 10?

Comment: Does Window prompt you to elevate when you run your VB6 app? What happens if you run both using "Run As Administrator"?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - so here is an interesting and weird thing. If i run Outlook as Administrator(explicitly) from the IDE (not run as administrator explicitly) - keep in mind I have local admin privelages - I have no problems at all. But If i open Outlook without explicitly RUN as ADMINISTRATOR I get the 429 ActiveX component can't create object error. Not sure what the heck is going on. I verified that I have elevated privelages for both outlook and IDE (in task manager) and I also checked with IT to check the network settings for my account just to be sure!

Comment: Do you see this from when you run your app from VB6 IDE? By default, it runs with elevated privileges. Do yo use the same problem if you run from VB6 executable from Windows Explorer?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko -In both cases, if I open Outlook explicityly as Administrator - it works fine (from IDE and .exe). So it has something to do with Outlook obviously and that's the only thing i could think off - since the CODE is identical.

Comment: iIt has nothing nto of do with OUtlook - COM system refuses to marshal out-of-proc COM calls between processes in different security contexts. So how do you start your exe?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - In this case I can run the .exe by just double clicking on it, or running it as administrator. In either case it doesn't matter. As long as Outlook is explicit as ADMIN - it works in both cases.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - to be more exact. I have a folder on my C: drive with .exe - i create a shortcut to my desktop. right click to properties - point it towards the C: drive folder / .exe.

Comment: That can only mean that your exe is running with elevated privileges in both cases. Does it embed a manifest?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko no - no manifest

Comment: Is your machine set up to prompt the user when elevation is requested, e.g. when you right click on the executable and select "Run As Administrator"??

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - No in this case no prompt exists. I simply right click Run As Admin and the application opens.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko is it okay to chat?

Comment: Turn the prompt back on - I bet in both cases your exe will cause a prompt. I'd rather not use chat - I am juggling a few other things at the same time.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - I hope I understand you correctly - basically the prompt to enter Administrator Passowrd??

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko  Or do you mean the UAC prompt - "do you want to allow th eprogram to make changes to computer"?

Comment: Yes, the UAC prompt.

Comment: @dmitrystreblechenko i will have to wait til tomorrow for helpdesk to help me with this. What will it mean if the exe causes the prompt?

Comment: That would mean your exe always runs with elevated rights, which means you either need to make sure Outlook si also elevated, or figure out why your exe is always elevated.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko i turned on UAC and I don't get prompt when I open the application in either Win 7 or Win 10